# Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-rm

When running this command as a Runbook:

```
Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName "mygroup" -Name "myname" -Tier "Premium" -WorkerSize "Small" -NumberofWorkers 1 -PerSiteScaling $FALSE
```

I get the error: `"Input string was not in a correct format."`

I noticed someone else report this on an earlier version of AzureRM and appears to be fixed in 5.0.0:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/5181

So is it possible that this bug still exists? How do I find out what version of AzureRM is being used within the automation Runbooks?

Comment: Of course I did the authentication steps, and I know they work because I have other automation scripts using those same steps and resizing other app service plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, the command works fine in local on my side.

> So is it possible that this bug still exists? How do I find out what version of AzureRM is being used within the automation Runbooks?

I think it may caused by the bug, you could check the powershell module version of runbook in your **automation account** -> **Modules**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just opened that link, and ... the modules are quite old, I have clicked the Update Modules button, and will see how that does.

Comment: Modules are updated now but I can't try again until out of hours, so I will comment tomorrow on how it went. Thanks.

Comment: Solved. Thanks!